# Getting object name from member value

Tags: c++, arduino

I have the following structure and need to get the corresponding Tag name (object name) when given the value of ID.

Ideally I will have a function: `GetName(id)` that returns the name.

e.g. GetName(0x73, 0xD5, 0xB7, 0xAC) will return tag RED1

```
enum class Color { red, green };

struct Tag {
  uint8_t id[4];
  Color color;
};

Tag RED1 = { { 0x73, 0xD5, 0xB7, 0xAC }, Color::red } ;
Tag RED2 = { { 0x7E, 0x27, 0x49, 0x4E }, Color::red } ;
Tag RED3 = { { 0x02, 0xFD, 0x06, 0x40 }, Color::red } ;
Tag GREEN1 = { { 0xAB, 0xEC, 0x68, 0x80 }, Color::green } ;
Tag GREEN2 = { { 0xEE, 0x20, 0x50, 0x4E }, Color::green } ;
Tag GREEN3 = { { 0x27, 0x06, 0x40, 0x73 }, Color::green } ;
```

Comment: Seems like you're looking for a `map`, have a look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)

Comment: You can't get the identifier of a variable as a value, you need to maintain your own table.